# Recognizing texts of a pnm image using gocr in SLES11

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, text-parsing

In my program trying to read character of a PNM image file like

> gocr -i $pnm > $txt

**and getting this message**

> threshold: Value<=gmin
>
> thresholdValue out of range 0..255, reset to 128
>
> no boxes found - stopped

Looke into the source **otsu.c** but not clear also google doesn’t help much on this topic.

Any idea what might possibly be gone wrong here.?

Note: My system is SLES11_SP2

Comment: Try converting your PNM image to another format and back to see if other programs are upset by your image, e.g. with ImageMagick `convert image.pnm image.png`

Comment: Ok right now trying a different thing but i will try as you suggested and will let you know.